# Merging multiple arrays stored in one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function which gets info from multiple APIs with callback to one variable (results):

```
function combineObjs(callback) {  
    function partialResult(results) {
        callback(results);
    };        
    searchFlickr.searchFlickr(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage, partialResult);
    searchUnsplash.searchUnsplash(searchTerm, searchCount, searchPage, partialResult);
}

combineObjs( function(results) {
    console.log(results)
});
```

As far as getting the data goes, it seems to work well. However, when asking for 2 results from each source, the data comes back as:

```
[ { id: 'flkr-13545844805',
    link: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/28596055@N02/13545844805' },
  { id: 'flkr-3474831728',
    link: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/9848951@N06/3474831728' } ]
[ { id: 'us-fRPxHaHwWwk',
    link: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/fRPxHaHwWwk' },
  { id: 'us-JXy99waA3Fo',
    link: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/JXy99waA3Fo' } ]
```

I have looked up merging arrays with javascript, but the only info I can find is to do with merging separate arrays, having to name at least 2 in order to push one into another. Since I only have one array those methods are not applicable.

I've also tried using a for each loop to separate each curly brace section but then I also need a way to comma separate them before putting them into another array. Not sure on the best approach here. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I believe the correct term for what you're looking for is "flatten" rather than "merge"? You already have an Array of Arrays? I'm trying to understand what you need.

Comment: I'm looking to get a single array with many items, which I want to use as an API end point for my front-end app. It looks like flatten is the right method however when trying to use it says flat is not a function

Comment: Did you write searchFlickr and searcUnsplash? I believe you want them to return a Promise, not to take a callback. Also, when using callbacks you should try to have them be the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you may want to do Array.prototype.reduce.

```
const multilevel = [["a","b"], ["c","d"]];

const flat = multilevel.reduce(function(flat_array, current){
    if(Array.isArray(current)) {
        return [...flat_array, ...current];
     } else {
         return [...flat_array, current];
     }
},[]); //["a","b","c","d"]
```

Comment: I've tested this with my code and it doesn't produce the desired result for some reason (it outputs the same result in the original question) edit: I ran the above code without adding my own data and it worked fine, thanks for providing the right answer it's just not working here. I will mark it correct soon if no solution comes up

Comment: Yes, actually my answer may not be what you need. I think our problem is a bit deeper than that. You are gathering two results asynchronously, so you're actually calling console.log twice, once for flickr once for unsplash.

Comment: You're right, after a little debugging I saw my code was making multiple callbacks. I will implement promises. Thanks for looking it over for me